# Are the windows at the airports UV protecting?

Tags: airports, health

Are the windows at the airports UV protecting?  If it depends, how can I know?

I'm asking as one sometime wait under the sun for a prolonged period of time waiting for the plane to board.

[image]

Comment: Most airports have tinted glass but how much UV protection it affords would vary from airport to airport, as I don't think there are any global legal standards for that.  Personally I just avoid sitting in chairs that the sun is shining on.

Comment: @Tom That's probably the best policy :-)

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, glass is [opaque for UV](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/3pcsub/do_windows_block_uv_light/) (partially opaque for near-ultraviolet) and plastic is even more so. This probably means that most of UV is blocked even without any special treatment.

Comment: Thanks. Are airport windows made of glass, plastic, or something else?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I think that depends on which airport.